# SQLQuery sumar columnas diferentes de una misma tabla y agruparlas por fechas

Tags: sql

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este query por favor. Tengo en una misma Tabla  fechas y unidades DIFERENTES.  Quisiera sumarlas y agruparlas por fechas.

Ejemplo.
Consultas

```
 SELECT 

T0.PRODUCTO AS 'Producto'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T0.[DFEC_DEV1] ,103) AS 'F.Dev 1'
,CONVERT(int, T0.DCANT_DEV1 ,103) AS 'Und Dev1'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T0.[DFEC_DEV2] ,103) AS 'F.Dev 2'
,CONVERT(int, T0.DCANT_DEV2 ,103) AS 'Und Dev2'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T0.[DFEC_DEV3] ,103) AS 'F.Dev 3'
,CONVERT(int, T0.DCANT_DEV3 ,103) AS 'Und Dev3'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T0.[FechaDate],103) AS 'Fecha de Venta'
 FROM TABLA T0

WHERE T0.[FechaDate] Between '01/06/2018' and '01/06/2018'
  AND T0.CCPRODUCTO ='LI'
  AND T0.DCANT_DEV1 != '0'
```

[image: Me muestra las fechas y unidades de un día de venta]

Subquerys

He probado una forma y las agrupe por fechas detallada. Con la siguiente consulta.

```
select T0.PRODUCTO as 'Producto'
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T0.[DFEC_DEV1] ,103)  AS 'Fechas Devoluciones'
  , CONVERT(int, T0.DCANT_DEV1 ,103)  as 'Devoluciones Und'
from
(
    select  T0.PRODUCTO,T0.[DFEC_DEV1],(T0.DCANT_DEV1)
    from TABLA T0
   Where T0.[FechaDate] Between '01/06/2018' and '01/06/2018'
  and T0.PRODUCTO ='LI'
  AND T0.DCANT_DEV1!= '0'
  UNION ALL
    select  T0.PRODUCTO,T0.[DFEC_DEV2],(T0.DCANT_DEV2)
     from TABLA T0
      Where T0.[FechaDate] Between '01/06/2018' and '01/06/2018'
      and T0.PRODUCTO ='LI'
      AND T0.DCANT_DEV2!= '0'
  UNION ALL
    select  T0.PRODUCTO,T0.[DFEC_DEV3],(T0.DCANT_DEV3)
      from TABLA T0
    Where T0.[FechaDate] Between '01/06/2018' and '01/06/2018'
    and T0.PRODUCTO ='LI'
    AND T0.DCANT_DEV3!= '0'
  ) T0

group by T0.DCANT_DEV1,T0.PRODUCTO,T0.[DFEC_DEV1]
```

Quedando Así

[image: me muestra las devoluciones detallando la fecha]

Ahora quisiera que me ayudaran a Agruparlas el total por fechas, pero también indicar que en la F.Dev3  Puede estar una fecha del 31/05 o 29/05,etc

Quisiera que se mostrará asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Espera de sus comentarios, Gracias ..!!

Comment: Sin tocar mucho tus querys (porque no termino de entenderlos, parecen demasiado complejo para lo que necesitas) usa ese ultimo query como entrada de un query nuevo, y reagrupa...